# How to add GDAL output formats support to WCS requests in GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, gdal, wcs

I am running GeoServer 2.18.1 and I installed GDAL extension as well as GDAL native libraries (I tried several versions with the same result).
I followed this guide : https://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/downloads/releases/2.8.x-ld/doc/community/gdal/index.html.

I manage to get the GDAL formats in the Raster data sources so I assume GDAL extension is correctly installed.
I've set all the necessary environment variables.

But no new format appears in the ServiceMetadata section of the WCS 2.0 GetCapabilities document.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: I'm not sure there is any expectation for those formats to appear as output formats - do you have some reason to think they should?

Comment: This phrase in GeoServer documentation : "Once installed in GeoServer, a bunch of new supported formats will be listed in the ServiceMetadata section of the WCS 2.0 GetCapabilities document, e.g. image/jp2 and application/pdf."

Comment: Ah, that is the gdal-wcs extension

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if you have installed the [GDAL extension](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/raster/gdal.html) and not the [WCS GDAL extension](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/gdal/index.html). You need the file `geoserver-2.18-SNAPSHOT-gdal-wps-plugin.zip` or whichever version you are running (to match your GeoServer install), as opposed to `geoserver-2.18-SNAPSHOT-gdal-plugin.zip`. This is a community module so needs to be fetched from the nightly builds or built locally.

Comment: Yes, that's it! I was not really aware of community modules ans it was not very clear for me in the GeoServer documentation.
However, I only get two more formats (pdf and zip) in the GetCapabilities response, but not all the other gdal formats. Is there something else to configure ?
Another thing that is strange to me is that now when I use the WCS request builder three other new gdal formats have appeared, but when I try for example the GDAL-XYZ format, I get a response saying that this format is not supported...

Comment: Yes, the documentation for the output format explans what you have to setup: https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/gdal/index.html#customisation

Comment: As indicated, the gdal_translate.xml file is necessary only if gdal_translate is not available in the path, the GDAL_DATA environment variable is not set, or if the output formats needs tweaking. This is why I did not use it. Anyway, if I put the file as recommended, it does not change anything in the available output formats in the WCS capabilities, neither in the WCS request builder.